# Android: ListView in Fragment and Cursor Loader not receiving data?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, loader, simplecursoradapter

I'm pretty new to Android and at this stage my code is compiling, the data is loading into the database (as far as I can see with debugger), but doesn't display in ListView. I've searched for quite a while but everything in my code seems to be OK. So my question is: what could I possibly miss? Thank you in advance!
Below is my code for the fragment. It should get the data fetched by AsyncTask. AsyncTask gets the (weather)data from the server and inserts it into the database. And as far as I understand, when the data is inserted, the UI should be notified about the change, but something goes wrong there (or elsewhere).

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks <Cursor>  {

private String mLocation;
private static final int FORECAST_LOCADER = 0;

public static SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

// column names for the projection
private static final String[] FORECAST_COLUMNS = {
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry._ID,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE_TEXT,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP,
        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING
};

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public ForecastFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            null,
            new String[]{
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE_TEXT,
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP
            },
            new int[] {
                    R.id.list_item_date_textview,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                    R.id.list_item_high_textview,
                    R.id.list_item_low_textview
            },
            0
    );

    ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    lv.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOCADER, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String startDate = WeatherContract.getDbDateString(new Date());
    String sortOrder = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE_TEXT + " ASC";
    mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
    Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(mLocation, startDate);
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            weatherForLocationUri,
            FORECAST_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    Log.i("onLoadFinished", "" + data.getCount());
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

In the code above log message "onLoadFinished" says 0, I'm not sure if that's expected value, because breakpoints I installed show this procedure runs before the data is fetched. As for ListView, when I used ArrayAdapter with dummy data, data was displayed, but with simpleCursorAdapter it doesn't work so far.

The AsyncTask is being called in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements ForecastFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
//... 
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {    }
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateWeather();
}

public void updateWeather() {
    FetchWeatherTask fetchWeatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask(getApplicationContext());
    String userLocationPreference = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getApplicationContext());
    String userUnitsPreference = Utility.getPreferredUnits(getApplicationContext());
    fetchWeatherTask.execute(userLocationPreference, userUnitsPreference);
}
```

Here's the code from AsyncTask:

```
class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
     private Context mContext;
     public FetchWeatherTask(Context context) {
         mContext = context;
     }
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    ...// fetching data
    cVVector.add(weatherValues);                
    if (cVVector.size() > 0) {
        int nRecordsInserted = addWeatherData(cVVector);
    }
...//
}
//function inserting data into db
private int addWeatherData(Vector <ContentValues> cvValues) {
    ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues [cvValues.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < cvValues.size(); i++) {
        values[i] = cvValues.get(i);
        Log.d("addWeatherData", values[i].toString());
    }
    Uri uri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI;
    int nRecords = -1;
    nRecords = mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(uri, values);
    Log.i("insert records", "" + nRecords + " records inserted");
    return nRecords;
}
```

In the code above log messages print the data and say that 14 records were inserted (as expected).
Code for bulkInsert in the db:

```
@Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    int returnCount = 0;
    switch (match) {
        case WEATHER: {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                for (ContentValues value: values) {
                    long _id = db.insert(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                    if (_id != -1) {
                        returnCount++;
                    }
                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }
            catch (Exception err) {
                Log.e("bulkInsert", err.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                db.endTransaction();
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            returnCount = super.bulkInsert(uri, values);
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.i("bulkInsert", "" + returnCount + " records inserted");
    return returnCount;
}
```

So as far as I understand (I've checked with debugger), the transaction completes successfully and UI should be notified of the change with 
`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` but in the app I see blank screen and no records are displayed. So I'm not sure what to do, please help! Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** as asked in comments, I'm also adding the full code for the `WeatherContract` class:

```
public class WeatherContract {

public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.irina.sunshine.app";
public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

public static final String PATH_WEATHER = "weather";
public static final String PATH_LOCATION = "location";

public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyyMMdd";

public static class LocationEntry implements BaseColumns {
 // description of location table
 public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_LOCATION).build();
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.dir/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_LOCATION;

    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.item/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_LOCATION;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "location";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING = "setting";
// other fields
}

public static class WeatherEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_WEATHER).build();
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.dir/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_WEATHER;
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.item/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_WEATHER;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "weather";
    //foreign key for location table
    public static final String COLUMN_LOC_KEY = "location_id";
    //date stored as text in format yyyy-MM-dd
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_TEXT = "date";
    //weather id as returned by API to identify the icon
    public static final String COLUMN_WEATHER_ID = "weather_id";
    //weather data as returned by API
    //e.g. "clear" vs "sky is clear"
    public static final String COLUMN_SHORT_DESC = "short_desc";
    //min and max temp stored as floats
    public static final String COLUMN_MIN_TEMP = "min";
    public static final String COLUMN_MAX_TEMP = "max";
    //stored as float representing percentage
    public static final String COLUMN_HUMIDITY = "humidity";
    //stored as float representing percentage
    public static final String COLUMN_PRESSURE = "pressure";
    //stored as float representing mph
    public static final String COLUMN_WIND_SPEED = "wind";
    //meteorological degrees, e.g 0 is north, 180 is south, stored as floats
    public static final String COLUMN_DEGREES = "degrees";

    public static Uri buildWeatherUri(long id) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
    }

    public static Uri buildWeatherLocation(String locationSetting) {
        return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(locationSetting).build();
    }

    // the function used to build Cursor Loader in Fragment
    public static Uri buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(String locationSetting, String startDate) {
        return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                .appendPath(locationSetting)
                 //+ just added to create another / symbol in path, but it still doesn't match the URI
                .appendEncodedPath("")
                //-
                .appendQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE_TEXT, startDate)
                .build();
    }


    public static Uri buildWeatherLocationWithDate(String locationSetting, String date) {
        return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                .appendPath(locationSetting)
                .appendPath(date)
                .build();
    }

    public static String getLocationSettingFromUri(Uri uri) {
        return uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
    }

    public static String getDateFromUri(Uri uri) {
        return uri.getPathSegments().get(2);
    }

    public static String getStartDateFromUri(Uri uri) {
        return uri.getQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE_TEXT);
    }
}
}
```

So, CursorLoader is created with URI build in the function `buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate` listed above.

And here's the code for custom ContentProvider (I'll trim `bulkInsert` function here because I've already listed it in the main part of the question):

```
public class WeatherProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final int WEATHER = 100;
private static final int WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION = 101;
private static final int WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE = 102;
private static final int LOCATION = 300;
private static final int LOCATION_ID = 301;

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
private WeatherDbHelper dbHelper;

private static final SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder;

static {
    queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN "
            + WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME
            + " ON " +  WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME
            + "." + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY
            + " = " + WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME
            + "." + WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID
    );
}

private static final String sLocationSettingSelection =
        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME
        + "." + WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " = ? ";

private static final String sLocationSettingWithStartDateSelection =
        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME
                + "." + WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " = ? AND "
        + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE_TEXT + " >= ? ";

private static final String sLocationSettingAndDateSelection =
        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME
                + "." + WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " = ? AND"
                + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE_TEXT + " = ? ";


private Cursor getWetatherByLocationSetting(Uri uri, String[] projection, String sortOrder) {
    String locationSetting = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.getLocationSettingFromUri(uri);
    String startDate = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.getStartDateFromUri(uri);
    String[] selectionArgs;
    String selection;

    if (startDate == null) {
        selection = sLocationSettingSelection;
        selectionArgs = new String[]{locationSetting};
    } else {
        selectionArgs = new String[]{locationSetting, startDate};
        selection = sLocationSettingWithStartDateSelection;
    }
    return queryBuilder.query(dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
}

private Cursor getWetatherByLocationAndDateSetting(Uri uri, String[] projection, String sortOrder) {
    String locationSetting = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.getLocationSettingFromUri(uri);
    String date = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.getDateFromUri(uri);
    String[] selectionArgs;
    String selection;

    if (date == null) {
        selection = sLocationSettingSelection;
        selectionArgs = new String[]{locationSetting};
    } else {
        selection = sLocationSettingAndDateSelection;
        selectionArgs = new String[]{locationSetting, date};
    }
    return queryBuilder.query(dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
}

private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    final String authority = WeatherContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
    //just changed the order of URIs, but it still doesn't affect the result
    sUriMatcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_WEATHER + "/*/*", WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_WEATHER + "/*", WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_WEATHER, WEATHER);

    sUriMatcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_LOCATION, LOCATION);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_LOCATION + "/#", LOCATION_ID);
    return sUriMatcher;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    dbHelper = new WeatherDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor cursor =  null;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE: {
            cursor = getWetatherByLocationAndDateSetting(uri, projection, sortOrder);
            break;
        }
        case WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION: {
            cursor = getWetatherByLocationSetting(uri, projection, sortOrder);
            break;
        }
        case WEATHER: {
            cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION_ID: {
            cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID  + " = '" + ContentUris.parseId(uri) + "'",
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION: {
            cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }
        default: {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" Not supported uri! " + uri.toString());
        }
    }
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE: {
            return WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        }
        case WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION: {
            return WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
        }
        case WEATHER: {
            return WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
        }
        case LOCATION_ID: {
            return WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        }
        case LOCATION: {
            return WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
        }
        default: {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" Not supported uri! " + uri.toString());
        }
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Uri insertUri;
    final int matcher = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (matcher) {
        case WEATHER: {
            long _id = db.insert(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            if (_id > 0) {
                insertUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherUri(_id);
            } else {
                throw new SQLiteException(" Couldn't insert row in db " + uri);
            }
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION: {
            long _id = db.insert(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            if (_id > 0) {
                insertUri = WeatherContract.LocationEntry.buildLocationUri(_id);
            } else {
                throw new SQLiteException(" Couldn't insert row in db " + uri);
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" Not supported uri! " + uri.toString());
        }
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return insertUri;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int nRowsAffected = 0;
    final int matcher = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (matcher) {
        case WEATHER: {
            nRowsAffected = db.delete(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            if (nRowsAffected <= 0) {
                Log.d("Deleting rows ", " 0 rows affected by " + uri);
            }
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION: {
            nRowsAffected = db.delete(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            if (nRowsAffected <= 0) {
                Log.d("Deleting rows ", " 0 rows affected by " + uri);
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {

            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" Not supported uri! " + uri.toString());
        }
    }
    if ((nRowsAffected != 0) && (selection != null)){
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }
    return nRowsAffected;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int nRowsAffected = 0;
    final int matcher = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (matcher) {
        case WEATHER: {
            nRowsAffected = db.update(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            if (nRowsAffected <= 0) {
                Log.d("Updating rows ", " 0 rows affected by " + uri);
            }
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION: {
            nRowsAffected = db.update(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            if (nRowsAffected <= 0) {
                Log.d("Updating rows ", " 0 rows affected by " + uri);
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" Not supported uri! " + uri.toString());
        }
    }
    if (nRowsAffected != 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }
    return nRowsAffected;
}

@Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    // listed in the main part of the question
}
```

I hope this'll help you to pinpoint my problem. Thank you!

**UPD2:** So, thanks to comments, 
1) I've learned about the difference between path and query parameters in Uri (query parameters are not part of the path so Uri Matcher ignores them). 
2) When I've looked under the hood of my db code, it turned out my query returned no values, because I was recording wrong data as my foreign key. Well, everything works now.

Comment: what is `weatherForLocationUri`? does it point to your custom `ContentProvider`? if so, post the code

Comment: @pskink I've added the code for building `weatherForLocationUri` and my `ContentProvider` class. Thank you!

Comment: debug steb-by-step `WeatherProvider#query` method and see why it returns an empty `Cursor`

Comment: @pskink The problem so far seems to be with Uri matching. The URI `content://com.example.irina.sunshine.app/weather/95008/?date‌​=20170117` is not recognised as `WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE`, but a different one. In `buildUriMatcher` I specify this URI as `sUriMatcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_WEATHER + "/*/*", WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE);` and it doesn't work for some reason, and my URI matches to `sUriMatcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_WEATHER + "/*", WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION);` I'm reading about URI matching now, seems that everything is as it should be.

Comment: this is because `?date‌​‌​=20170117` is not part of `path`, it is a `query`, try to `Log.d` the value of `getPath()` and `getQuery()` and you will see

Comment: @pskink I see it now, so it seems that I can't and shouldn't differentiate between two Uris one of which has query and another doesn't. It's really strange, though, because this example is from a course on Android which I thought I could trust. I'll try to change my code to work with it. Thank you one more time for your help!

Comment: yes, just use `WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION` and test here if you have any `query` in your `Uri` - `getQueryParameter` / `getQueryParameters` / `getQueryParameterNames`